# Is there a guide to debugging Java processes in Eclipse across OSs?

Tags: java, windows, linux, eclipse, debugging

I have an application written in Java to run on Linux. I'm developing in Eclipse under windows. I would like to run the code on the Linux box and debug it on the Windows one remotely. I've found some information about how to do so, but it's pretty sparse. Does anyone have (or can point to) a complete explanation of the process?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Platform Debugger Architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jpda/) (JPDA) supports remote debugging. First, you need to enable remote debugging of your application by loading the JDWP agent for debugging into your application's JVM. Starting from Java 5.0, use the `-agentlib:jdwp` option. See [Sun VM Invocation Options](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation)) for all the details and examples<sup>1</sup>. 
Then, configure Eclipse to connect the debugger (check this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat)).

<sub><sup>1</sup> For releases prior to 5.0, the `-Xdebug` and `-Xrunjdwp` options are used.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cremdbug.htm) will give you the answer ... when it comes back. Alternatively a search in Eclipse Help for "remote debug" should bring up the same page.

For all of the gory details about how Java debugging works, refer to the [JDPA](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a guide](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) for remote debugging.